# How to live stream images in browser?

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, webrtc, httpserver

I am trying to create an app to mirror my phone's screen in a e-book reader's browser.
The idea is to continuously make screenshots and make them available from http server running on the phone.
So far I have succeeded in having an http server running on the phone and sharing the latest screenshot.
Now I would like to update the image in the browser automatically - which mechanics should I use - should the website pull the image every x milliseconds or can I push the changes from the server? The image transition should happen smoothly. The e-book's browser is somehow limited, for example it doesn't support html5-video and probably many other things.
I am using the basic dart httpServer (because my app is in flutter) and would prefer to keep it basic.
For testing I had a png Screenshot, but I would also like to optimize for greyscale and maybe try to do something with canvas (don't have experience here) if the browser supports it.

Main questions:
-is there an easy way to push changes from server to browser?
-how do I achieve a smooth transition between images (and skip refresh if the image didn't change)?
-which alternatives are there to using images?
-can canvas help me somehow?

Comment: here is what html5 standards my e-reader browser supports http://html5test.com/s/af07c24c02743dd1.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing to use here is WebRTC. The browser provides [getDisplayMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getDisplayMedia) that allows you to either capture a tab or the whole display of a device.

You can then connect your two devices, and stream the capture live. The other nice thing is that it will be P2P and you should see sub-second latency (and you don't have the added complexity of running a HTTP server).

All you need is a signaling server to send the Offer/Answer/ICE Candidates between the two peers. These messages are just 'bootstrap' details to get the call started.

---

If getDisplayMedia doesn't work on the device you can add WebRTC via a native app. [flutter-webrtc](https://github.com/cloudwebrtc/flutter-webrtc) is one possible solution.

Comment: I am not sure if this will work, as want to make screenshots from any app/display the user is using and not from my app itself

Comment: my e-book browser doesn't support webrtc - see my results http://html5test.com/s/af07c24c02743dd1.html